# POSTing form data in Zapier's NodeJS module

Tags: node.js, zapier

This is my code I'm trying in the NodeJS module in Zapier. But apparently, you cannot use `FormData` with Zapier. I've tried adding the module with `const FormData = require('form-data');` but Zapier tells me it can't find that module. When I don't include the `require` I get that FormData is not defined. My full code is below. Is there an alternative for posting form data in the `body` in Zapier's nodeJS module?

```
            formData.append('api_key', 'XXX');
            formData.append('sig', 'YYY');
            formData.append('format','json');
            formData.append('json','{"id": "pleasedeletethis@gmail.com}"');
const res = await 
fetch('https://api.sailthru.com/user', { method: 'POST', body: formData })
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    });
return json;
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting around this by preparing the data I needed (that required some JS manipulation) using the NodeJS zap, but then sending the actual data using Zapier's webhooks zap that lets you construct a POST with all the data as form data.